# ORA 01797- operator must be followed by any or all

Tags: reporting-services, oracle11g, subquery

I am testing a condition like this in the where clause of a subquery. But I am getting the error "operator must be followed by any or all" when I execute the SSRS report.

dbase is oracle. And i need to use IN with parameter because the parameter in SSRS report is multivalued. I am using a separate function to generate dates that go in :P_Date.
I need to check if this date is = or < or null . All three conditions need to be tested.

```
where 
trunc(tt.fyh_fecha) IN (:P_Date) OR
trunc(tt.fyh_fecha) <(:P_Date) OR 
trunc(tt.fyh_fecha) IS NULL AND
tc.cod_tree = 'blue' AND
tt.color_flower = 'pink'
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesnt seem directly possible - you are trying to use a parameter containing an array of values against the < operator which only expects one value.  Your design doesnt make any logical sense to me either (<= multiple dates?), but anyway ...

I would add a join to a Calendar / Date Dimension table, where I would apply the `IN (:P_Date)` criteria to get a list of Date values as a deliberate cross join.

Then I would replace:

`trunc(tt.fyh_fecha) IN (:P_Date) OR`

`trunc(tt.fyh_fecha) <(:P_Date) OR`

with:

`trunc(tt.fyh_fecha) <= Dim_Date.Date_Value`